# Creation of duplicate node with same relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a node (a)  , i want to create new node (c) and relate it to all nodes related to (a) with the same old relationships (a) related to other nodes in the graph??

i tried the following cypher :

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) where ID(a)=  42
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rels, a, b
create (c) set c.name='علامات'
FOREACH (rel in rels |
       CREATE (b)-[r:LINKED_TO]->(c)
       SET r+=rel
)
```

but it created multiple (c) nodes not just one.

i tried the cypher below but it created multiple (c) nodes with new relations not only one node.

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) where ID(a)=  42
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rels, a, b
create (c) set c.name='علامات'
FOREACH (rel in rels |
       CREATE (b)-[r:LINKED_TO]->(c)
       SET r+=rel
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#clone-nodes).

For example:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE ID(a) = 42
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships([a]) YIELD input, output
RETURN input, output
```

Comment: but this method result is the same node copy , i want new node with custom attributes with the same relationships.

Comment: i got it thanks
MATCH (a)
WHERE ID(a) = 42
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships([a]) YIELD input, output
set  output.name='xyz'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run a following query

```
CREATE (clone {name: "علامات"})
WITH clone
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) where ID(a)=  42
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rels, collect(b) as nodes, clone
WITH rels, nodes, clone, range(0, size(rels)-1) AS indexes
UNWIND indexes AS i
WITH clone, rels[i] as rel, nodes[i] as relNode
create (clone)-[nr:LINKED_TO]->(relNode) SET nr += rel
```

It will create a new node, relations accordingly, but it is not a generic query, **and it will not copy labels and direction of relationships**.
To have more universal query it is better to duplicate everything with [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#clone-nodes) and change properties of created node afterwards.